# iOS podcast app that supports listener notes

Tags: ios, note-taking, podcast

Is there a good podcast app for iOS that will let me take notes of the podcasts I stream (or at least save)?

I often want to jot down a time and topic of interest as I listen.  It would be nice to have that content stored with my playlists.